# How to extract a list-like value from a dropdown menu selection using altair

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, altair

My partial code below is to try to exclude clients selected thru using dropdown menu. However, I can't get list like object from selection.

```
def cal_h(df, selected_clients=None):
    if selected_clients:
        df_filtered = df[~df[‘Client_Name].isin(selected_clients)]
……….
    return new_dataframe

clients_dropdown=alt.binding_select(options=clients, name=‘Exclude Client(s)’)
clients_selector=alt.selection_single(fields=[‘Client_Name’], bind=clients-dropdown)

chart_selected_clients=alt.Chart(cal_h(df, selected_clients=clients_selector)).mark_bar().encode(
………..
.add_selection(clients_selector
).transform_filter(
clients_selector
)
```

I tried a lot of different options such as clients_selector.fields[0], clients_selector.Client_Name, etc. I am open minded to another solution to exclude the selection from the dataframe.